# Framework Not Found -- OpenCV

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, frameworks

I am having issues getting OpenCV to work with iOS and Xcode. I am running OS X 10.9.3 and Xcode 5.1.1. To install OpenCV and build the framework for iOS, I followed these [instructions](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html#ios-installation) exactly.

I then created a new project, and dragged in opencv2.framework from Finder into Link Binary with Libraries. After building the project, I get:

```
ld: framework not found opencv2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I noticed that in the right sidebar there is a question mark next to opencv2.framework I read that this is due to the framework not being included in source control. I selected the framework and clicked Source Control > Add "opencv2.framework" The question mark doesn't go away and the build still fails with the same error.

Usually when Xcode cannot find a file, the file's text is red. It is not in this case.

Does anyone what the problem is?

Comment: This might help http://aptogo.co.uk/2011/09/opencv-framework-for-ios/

Comment: I had the same issue. I removed it from pods and installed it again. Maybe you should try the same.. and when I added the framework manually, it wasn't red but missed all the header files included!!

Answer (score 0):

Your link is dead, but I'll assume your instructions were similar to the ones [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d7/d88/tutorial_hello.html).

I managed to get Xcode to build by dragging the framework into the XCode project, like shown below. Notice how it's in Libraries and in the left-hand Navigator.

[image]

Following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@yiweini/opencv-with-swift-step-by-step-c3cc1d1ee5f1) might help also. I followed that tutorial and managed to get it working today.